# Getting an exception like InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I'm making one web application for online shoes, using spring boot framework and I'm trying to build a relation between Product and Purchase table. In that I assume that in a one purchase we can have multiple products. So I've done some code according to this relation and in that, I'm getting an exception like **InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException** and the subsequent exception is **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'purchase_purchaseID'**.

May be my relation is wrong or invalid. So please help me in this issue.

You can find more details as below:

My first entity class **Product**

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "productID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int productID;
    
    @Column(name = "subCatID", nullable = false)
    private int subCatID;
    
    @Column(name = "productName", nullable = false)
    private String productName;
    
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Purchase.class)
    private Purchase purchase;
    
    public int getSubCatID() {
        return subCatID;
    }

    public void setSubCatID(int subCatID) {
        this.subCatID = subCatID;
    }

    public int getProductID() {
        return productID;
    }

    public void setProductID(int productID) {
        this.productID = productID;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String procutName) {
        this.productName = procutName;
    }

    public Purchase getPurchase() {
        return purchase;
    }

    public void setPurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        this.purchase = purchase;
    }
    
}
```

My second entity class is **Purchase**

```
@Entity
public class Purchase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "purchaseID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int purchaseID;
    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "productID")
    private Set<Product> product;
    
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userID")
    private User user;
    
    @Column(name = "createdDate")
    private Date createdDate;

    public int getPurchaseID() {
        return purchaseID;
    }

    public void setPurchaseID(int purchaseID) {
        this.purchaseID = purchaseID;
    }

    public Set<Product> getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Set<Product> product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
```

And then I'm trying to access to particular URL action like **/products** at that time this exception gets thrown. You can also find out this code from the controller side.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/products")
    public ModelAndView getProducts(HttpServletRequest req) {
        session = req.getSession(false);
        ModelAndView mav = null;
        if(session != null) {
            List<Product> productList = productService.getAllProducts();
            mav = new ModelAndView("Product");
            mav.addObject(productList);
        }
        else {
            mav = new ModelAndView("Login");
        }
        return mav;
    }
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2322) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2075) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'purchase_purchaseID'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1662) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:615) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:537) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7417) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3488) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'purchase_purchaseID'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1662) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:615) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:537) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7417) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3488) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:262) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:237) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
```

Comment: I suppose your ORM doesn't let you see what SQL it actually generates and sends to SQL Server. Which is what some people love about ORMs, but what we should all hate about them.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sorry sir, I did not get you. Can you elaborate more on what you've said And what should I do here in this case?

Comment: I mean that your ORM is generating a query that includes a reference to a column named `purchase_purchaseID` but isn't showing you the actual query it's sending (or how it came about to think such a column existed). ORMs work great until they don't.

Comment: [Relevant tweet from last month](https://twitter.com/AaronBertrand/status/1494725734153216003)

Comment: @AaronBertrand haha. I understood your point based on later explanation. Thank you